# image blank with 0 size after download via curl from google

Tags: php, image, curl

hi there I want download gmail profile image like this:

```
$src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MsxFngq63hA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAFc/kKIrjln2a_s/photo.jpg?sz=200';
```

with this curl:

```
    $ch = curl_init ($src);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $fp=fopen("./imageProcess.jpg","w+");
    fwrite($fp,  $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
```

but result image is blank with 0 size.

what is the wrong?

Comment: Probably google used cookie to check if the user has access to the image. Also another thing you can do is to mimic a browser by adding user agent *Edit* That is not the case because i just tried the url in terminal and it is working. Let me try your code and see the error

Comment: have you tried adding `fflush($fp);` before closing the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly your code, But this one is shorter and not *curl complicated*

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents("a.jpg", $current);
?>
```

Hope this helps, unless you also want to edit the raw headers

Comment: thanks fr the answer. But I got this error: ` Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` and with a blank and ziro image file again.

Comment: i just checked the script and it is working fine over here, let me make a gist of the exact file and send it over

Comment: here is the link https://gist.github.com/georoot/62a8e09875e309c75e7672acc1024af3

Comment: thanks. openssl was problem but your code works too.